# How to prove the anti-derivative of a periodic function?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to prove that the anti-derivative of a periodic function is not necessarily periodic? (Without considering random examples)

I know that integral of $$ f(x) = f(a+x) $$ is $$ F(x) + c $$

Comment: Can you consider whether $F$ has a limit at $+\infty$? Can you show that such a limit, if it exists, must be $\pm\infty$?

Comment: If $f$ is $T$-periodic with mean value $0$ then $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y)dy$ is $T$-periodic, in general $F(x) - m T x$ is $T$-periodic with $m$ the mean value

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample would be the simplest way. But since you don't want this, here's an alternative proof:

Assume that the periodic function $f$ with period $a$ has a periodic antiderivative $F$. Then we have
$$\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx = F(a)-F(0) = 0$$
where the latter equality is due to the periodicity of $F$.
However, if $f(x)$ is periodic, then so is $g(x):=f(x)+c$ with $c\ne 0$. But then,
$$\int_0^a g(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx +\int_0^a c\,\mathrm dx
= ac \ne 0.$$
Therefore $g(x)$ does not have a periodic antiderivative.

Comment: You proof somehow implicitely assumes that the periodic function is not the zero function. The true statement would be rather any periodic function with periodic antiferivtive is the zero function.

Comment: @lalala: It nowhere assumes that. Clearly also for the zero function, we have $F(a)-F(0)=0$. In case you meant $f(x)$ is the zero function, then that still works: The zero function has a periodic antiderivative (namely its antiderivatives are exactly the constant functions), and of course also for constant functions we have $F(a)-F(0)=0$.

Comment: Your proif cannot work for f beeing the zero function (the  conclusion doesnt hold)

Comment: @lalala: How does the conclusion not hold? If $f$ is the zero function, then $g$ is a non-zero constant function. And a non-zero constant function does not have a periodic antiderivative, does it?

Comment: Ah, ok now i see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any strictly positive periodic function $f$. Then, any antiderivative of $f$ is strictly increasing and so not periodic.